# Hyper-V can't change MAC address C9-ED-D0-CE-BF-7F?

Tags: hyper-v

When I change static MAC address then system will show:

> Error applying Advanced Features Changes - Failed to modify device "Synthetic Ehernet Port"

- I check no Device using this MAC
- Change `C8-ED-D0-CE-BF-7F`, `C6-ED-D0-CE-BF-7F`, `C4-ED-D0-CE-BF-7F` are ok but `C1-ED-D0-CE-BF-7F`, `C3-ED-D0-CE-BF-7F`, `C5-ED-D0-CE-BF-7F` will show this error

This server used this MAC code before October 8th, but after October 8th Hyper-V change this MAC and no one change it.

[image]

Comment: Probably because you are not supposed to use a MAC address with an odd first octet, since such an address is considered a multicast Ethernet address.

Comment: [Wikipedia MAC address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) : "The **b0 bit** distinguishes multicast and unicast addressing and the **b1 bit** distinguishes universal and locally administered addressing."

Comment: Really appreciate! could you answer below?